# country based redirection in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this url :

```
www.example.com/index.php?cn=us
```

to

```
www.example.com/us/
```

is it possible in htaccess? and how?

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite on your server or other similar lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?cn=$1
```

And this shows this works with any two letter country code

index.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['cn'];
?>
```

Comment: Great. Saved lot of time...Thanks.